# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[X,X] - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

While starting my new JavaFX application with a simple code down below

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" minHeight="200"minWidth="200" prefHeight="250" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="AudioVideoController.FXMLDocumentController">

</BorderPane>
```

I have encountered following exceptions:

> ***Exception in Application start method***
>
> **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>
> **Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException**
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application *start method***
>
> **Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at *[row,col]:[9,62]***

However, even though I am programming for 4 years in JavaFX these exceptions showed me for the first time and I was quite amazed to see some new tricks old JavaFX pulls out.

So what is causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was rushing creating simple gui for my application, I accidentely put two parameters one to another,
without an empty space, therefore XMLStreamReader objected while reading params

> minWidth="200"prefHeight="200"

bundled together in the next() method not validated against DTD.

Therefore, for all future situations, make sure empty space exist between params called in your XML file which follows DTD, as shown below:

> minWidth="200" prefHeight="200"